# Dynamic routes not working in React with Caddy

Tags: reactjs, url-rewriting, centos, caddy, caddyfile

I have a React Application. I am using some routes that receives parameters in the URL (by GET), for example `myapp.com/products/1` that works pretty good in local enviroment but no in my CentOS server. I have to mention that I am using `npm run build` to generate the static files.

For other side, I have running Caddy as HTTP server in the CentOS server, there I have problem only with the routes that includes parameters, so now am wondering if caddy have something to be with this issue.

[Here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#static-server) the React people say:

> If you’re using Apache, you need to create a .htaccess file in the
>   public folder that looks like this:

```
 Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

So, how can I do that in Caddy. I have currently these lines for the site:

```
mysite.com {
   root PathToProject/build/
   log logs/pagelog.log
}
```

What is missing in order to can use parameters in the URL?

Answer (score 1):

I have this config in my Caddyfile

```
rewrite {
  if    {path} not_match ^\/0.0.0.0
  to    {path} {path}/ /?_url={uri}
}
```

See if that helps, it took care of my routing issue (similar to what u have mentioned) for React App.